# jQuery, form validation, message after validation of .each field

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, each

EDIT FINAL: OMG, i finally found out what goes wrong!! i allmost can't believe, i am testing this piece for 8 hours non stop, and finally...... i am still not sure what and how and why, but it appears that for some reason (i think) i cant have different values for the re-variable, because there are different fields, 1 time, its for a text and the other time for a number, for example, if i just define different variables for each possible regex in stead of redefining it, there is no problem! o.O

i have posted the code that i use now in a reply under this post

thanks so much for anyone that have spend some time reading and thinking about this!!

if anyone has ideas on why it went wrong, i am very interested!

---

original question:

cant find the logic why this wont work.. i have a form that i want to validate, each field should be validated onBlur: works perfect, on submit it should validate each field: works perfect, when there is some kind of error, it should show a message and return false: does not work.. for some reason, the submit function just does not want to do anything after the .each, it wont even work when i dont do any check on errors, and just want an alert after the .each..

EDIT: after the mentions of some little errors, it unfortunately still wont work.. here is the total code, inclusive the checkfield-function (the error messages are in dutch, in case you're wondering ;))

EDIT2: after more testing, it seems its not because of the checkform function, but something to do with the regex test ( if (!re.test(fieldvalue)) ) that gets the code stuck.. cant find the problem though.. any thoughts would be much appreciated!

EDIT3: why wont the checkfieldfunction with the regex not loop with .each?? anyone?? i am really desperate.. -.-

```
function trim(str){
  return str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
}

function checkfield(field){  

  var output = 'validate' + $(field).attr("name");
  var type = $(field).attr("type");
  if ($(field).hasClass('required')){var required = 1;}

  //set patterns for different types
  if (type == 'text') { var re = /^[A-Za-z0-9 -._]+$/;} 
  if (type == 'number') { var re = /^[\d -.]+$/;} 
  if (type == 'email') { var re = /^[\w-_.]+@[\w]+\.[\w]*\w\w$/;} 
  if (type == 'date') { var re = /^[0-3][0-9][\/-][0-1][0-9][\/-](19|20)[0-9][0-9]$/;} 

  var fieldvalue = trim(field.value); //trim value of input

  if (required == 1 && emptyString.test(fieldvalue)) { //is required field filled in? if no, return false
     $('#'+output).html('Invullen van onderstaand veld is verplicht!');

     field.focus();
     return false;  
    }

  else if (fieldvalue != "" && type != '' && !re.test(fieldvalue)) { //input according to pattern? if no: place message, return false

     if (type == 'email') {$('#'+output).html('Dit is geen correct e-mailadres!');}
     else if (type == 'date') {$('#'+output).html('Dit is geen correcte datum!');}
     else {$('#'+output).html('U gebruikt tekens die niet zijn toegestaan!');}

     field.focus(); 
     return false;
    }

  else if (fieldvalue != ""){ //when no error and filled in, empty messagebox, return true 
     $('#'+output).html('');

     return true; 
    }

  else if (required == 0 && fieldvalue == ""){//is empty but not required, empty messagebox, return true
     $('#'+output).html('');
     document.getElementById(output).innerHTML = '';
     return true;   
    }
}


$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#userform input").blur(function(){
  checkfield(this);
  })

  $("#userform").submit(function(){
    var errs = 0;
    $("#userform input").each(function(){
      if (!checkfield(this)) errs +=1;
    }); 
    if (errs>0) {alert('one or more fields are not correctly filled in'); return false;}

  })
});
```

---

new code that works!!

if anyone likes to use a simple form validation, feel free ;) (the spaces are not exactly nice, but thats beacuse my code editor has different rules than this website..)

```
function trim(str){
  return str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
}

function checkfield(field){  
  var output = 'validate' + $(field).attr("name");
  var type = $(field).attr("type");

  if ($(field).hasClass('required')){var required = 1;}
  var re_text = /^[A-Za-z0-9 -._]+$/;   
  var re_number = /^[\d -.]+$/; 
  var re_email = /^[\w-_.]+@[\w]+\.[\w]*\w\w$/; 
  var re_date = /^[0-3][0-9][\/-][0-1][0-9][\/-](19|20)[0-9][0-9]$/;    
  var emptyString = /^\s*$/ ;

  var error = 0;

  var fieldvalue = trim(field.value); //trim value of input

if (required == 1 && emptyString.test(fieldvalue)) { //is required field filled in? if no, return false
   $('#'+output).html('Invullen van onderstaand veld is verplicht!');
     field.focus();
     return false;  
}

else if (!emptyString.test(fieldvalue)){
 if (type == 'text'){    
   if (!re_text.test(fieldvalue)) {       
     $('#'+output).html('U gebruikt tekens die niet zijn toegestaan!'); 
         error = 1;          
     field.focus();  
       return false;         
   }
     else {$('#'+output).html(''); return true; }    
 }

 if (type == 'number'){  
   if (!re_number.test(fieldvalue)) {     
     $('#'+output).html('U gebruikt tekens die niet zijn toegestaan!');              
     error = 1;
         field.focus();  
       return false;         
   }    
     else {$('#'+output).html(''); return true; }    
 }

 if (type == 'email'){   
   if (!re_email.test(fieldvalue)) {      
     $('#'+output).html('Dit is geen correct e-mailadres!');                 
     error = 1;
         field.focus();  
       return false;         
   }    
     else {$('#'+output).html(''); return true; }    
 }

 if (type == 'date'){    
   if (!re_date.test(fieldvalue)) {       
     $('#'+output).html('Dit is geen correcte datum!');              
     error = 1;
         field.focus();  
       return false;         
   }    
     else {$('#'+output).html(''); return true; }    
 }  
}     

else if (required == 0 && emptyString.test(fieldvalue)){//is empty but not required, empty messagebox, return true
 $('#'+output).html('');
     document.getElementById(output).innerHTML = '';
     return true;   
}

}


$(document).ready(function(){

$("#userform input").blur(function(){
checkfield(this);
})

  $("#userform").submit(function(){
var errs = 0;


$("#userform .form").each(function(){
  if (!checkfield(this)) errs +=1;
        //checkfield(this);
}); 
if (errs>0) {alert('one or more fields are not correctly filled in'); return false;}
//alert(errs); return false;

})
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't stop the alert from working, but you have a typo there with errs = +1 instead of errs += 1.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to switch around the + and = in your .each()

```
if (!checkfield(this)) errs += 1;
```

Comment: ah yeah, little error that did not get its testing yet, as it is not the reason that it doesnt work, but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As Brad Falk pointed out, you should be using `errs += 1` rather than `errs =+1`. However, there are a few other errors as well.

You're missing a semi-colon after the `.each()` call. This is the only thing I can see that may cause your problem.

In addition to that, your `return false` isn't part of the `if` statement block, so it will always prevent form submission even when there are no validation errors - this may be what you want, but since I can't see any evidence of an AJAX post instead, may cause you problems in the future.

Comment: thanks, a little sloppy of me, wanted to test the return without the test and forgot to but it back in, also dit take care of the other errors you mention, cant let it work though.. maybe it is in the checkfield after all, i'll update my question with the total code

Comment: First thing to check is that you don't have any Javascript errors showing up in the browser. If you're using Firefox, and you don't have it yet, I'd suggest installing Firebug.

Comment: thanks, i use it on html and css, never used it for javascript, dont know how to yet, but i'll look for a tutorial on the web :)

Comment: are you able to tell why the loop wont work with the regext test? it works for 1 field test, but goes wrong in the loop..

Comment: @DavidvanDiepen Any chance you could edit the question to include some HTML to go along with the Javascript code?